# Solving for diameter of a glass tube to hold water

Tags: surface-tension

I have a tube with length $l$. I then fill it with water. I then turn the tube upside down. What is the diameter as a function of $l$ such that the water does not spill out?

I need to do a force or energy balance I think. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a water barometer of some sort?

Comment: @barrycarter Basically, I have a glass tube that is closed at one end. I then fill the glass tube with water. Then I want to turn the tube upside down. I want to find the diameter as a function of the length of the tube "l" such that the water stays in the tube.

Comment: OK, I missed the "surface tension" tag on your question. You're looking to see when gravity is stronger than the electrical force that binds water to glass (eg, resulting in a meniscus).

Comment: @barrycarter How do I express this in equations as a function of l though?

Comment: Specifying l is not enough. At a minimum you need to specify d, the inner diameter of the tube. For instance, at 1 meter diameter, l is zero.